# How to replace duplicated 'slash' into a single slash from a string?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

How can I replace duplicated 'slash' from a string?

For instance,

```
str = '/estate//info//';  
alert(fragment.replace(/\/\/+/, "/"));
```

result,

```
/estate/info//
```

But I am after,

```
/estate/info/
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
str = '/estate//info//';  
alert(str.replace(/\/\/+/g, "/"));  
// where 'g' will do the global search and replace it with single '/'
```

Answer (score 3):

try this,

```
str = '/estate//info//';  
alert(fragment.replaceAll("//", "/"));
```

Comment: will alert `/estate/info//`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try

```
  var val = "\\val1\\val2\\val3";
  val = val.substr(0, val.lastIndexOf("\\"));
  alert(val);
```

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fRUUd/1356/)